# How to save binary data in MySQL using PHP?

Tags: php

i want to download the image from one server, and want to save the binery data into mysql blob field. but its not working.

1. if i am displaying the $picture1 then it shows the un-readable characters. byt $picture2 is not displaying.
2. if i try to save it in the table, then its not saving in the table.

how can i save this into my blob field.

```
$picture1 = GetImageFromUrl($url);
$picture2 = addslashes(fread(fopen($picture, "r"), filesize($picture)));

print_r($picture1)
print_r($picture2)

function GetImageFromUrl($link)
{

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$link); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$result=curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch); 
return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try encoding it with base64 before saving in your database field:

```
echo base64_encode($picture1);
```

And to read out from database, you need to decode it:

```
echo base64_decode($picture);
```

But be sure to send the right headers with it, for example:

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
```

But please read this before: [**Storing Images in DB - Yea or Nay?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay) and consider if you really want to save it in your database.

I am strictly against it, but it's in your power

Comment: Also, be aware that the size of base64 encoded data is roughly 1.37 times bigger than the size of the original data.

Comment: its displaying the binary codes, but not saving it in the database.